# Determine if a XmlNode is empty or null in C#?

Tags: c#, null, dataset, xmlnode

The following code takes an `XmlNode` data type and populates a `DataSet` object with the `XmlNode` content.  Then I write the dataset's content to file.

```
public void PopulateDataSet(XmlNode node)
{
    XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(node);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(reader);

    system.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    string name = string.Format("{0}{1}_{2}.xml", Utility.XmlOutputPath, Utility.XmlOutputFileName, guid.ToString());

    //need to write "Node empty" to file if XmlNode object is empty of null
    ds.WriteXml(name, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
}
```

The problem is that I encountered one scenario that it will not write the content to file.  How do I determine if a `XmlNode` object is null or empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the node parameter is null or has `InnerText` or `InnerXml` properties are null or empty, immediately when you enter the method before even creating the `XmlNodeReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlElement instead for get if the node is empty.

```
XmlElement currNode = (XmlElement) doc.DocumentElement.LastChild;
if (currNode.IsEmpty)
{
    ...
}
```